# Is it possible to control xlabel stepping label in subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, subplot

I believe this is an old issue about subplot. However, I could not be able to find my answer.

**Question:**
Is it possible to let my `subplot` identically stepping the `x-label`?

```
y_label = 'db_server_6a_2018_df_IL1-A'

f, ax_list = plt.subplots(12, 1, gridspec_kw = {
    'height_ratios': [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
    'width_ratios': [30]
}, figsize=(20, 40))
for month in range(1, 12 + 1):
    start_dt = datetime.datetime(2018, month, 1)
    end_dt = start_dt + relativedelta(months=1)
    window_df = df[(start_dt < df['Time']) & (df['Time'] <= end_dt)]

    ax = ax_list[month-1]
    ax.plot(window_df['Time'], window_df[y_label])
    ax.set_ylabel(start_dt.strftime('%B'))
    ax.set_xlabel('datetime')
f.savefig(y_label + '.png')
```

Here is the output
[image: timestep in x axis does not start from first date]

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried to set xticks()  and xlim(), namely, respectively,  to set a new list of locations where ticks should be placed and to set a tuple of the new x-axis limits, for each subplots?

[xticks documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=xticks#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks)

[xlim documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html)

They should also work well with the subplots.

Another solution could be to use:

```
plt.subplot(something, sharex=ax, sharey=ax)
```

where, as written in the documentation

```
sharex, sharey : Axes, optional
Share the x or y axis with sharex and/or sharey. 
The axis will have the same limits, ticks, and scale as the axis of the shared axes.
```

P.S. I can not write a comment because I do not have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @ElidorDD answer. I just known the correct wording from him. Here is the answer to my question which is inherited from `matplotlib.axes.Axes` class not `matplotlib.pyplot`

```
ax.xaxis.grid(True)
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.set_xticks([datetime.datetime(2018, month,1), 
               datetime.datetime(2018, month, 7),
               datetime.datetime(2018, month, 14),
              datetime.datetime(2018, month, 21),
              datetime.datetime(2018, month, 28)])
monthyearFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(monthyearFmt)
```

[image: Same tick for all months, but keep picture short just 3 months]